# Model deleted from PowerDesigner repository

Tags: repository, powerdesigner

I am working on Power Designer 16.1, the repository is installed on a Linux server.
I have an issue with the repository sometimes dropping my models, in most cases I am able to check-in the models to the repository and check-out correctly, but sometimes after I correctly check-in a model it seems that it is being deleted from the repository.
I am not sure but I think the problem may occur when two (or more) people tries to check-in the same model at the same time (or overlapping), and that causes the model to disappear from the repository.
Any idea or workaround to fix this?

Comment: This kind of behavior reminds me of a known, and fixed, problem, where the versions of the newly checked-in model, are not correctly linked, especially in multi-user context. I don't think there's a solution/workaround apart from getting a update which would fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Does reading logs of PowerDesigner can help to clarify the reason?

Maybe repository has it's own server logs?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you upgrade to the latest version. They fix tons of bugs in each patch, and a lot of them have to do with the repository. It is very likely that this will fix it.

But we still found it best to have ONE designated person do check-in on models, to avoid strange issues.

If you use any replication between models, the repository will act even stranger than it already does, so if you can, try removing replicating properties from your models.

Apart from that, we make daily database backups of the repository and we sometimes have to use them too.

Another thing that may help: in the PowerDesigner Repository Administration menu you can select to rebuild indexes, if you have the logon/password for the account that installed the repository. Rebuilding indexes has solved several nasty prob

And now a bit off-topic: in my experience (working with the repository for 3+ years now), it has always been very buggy. Even with the highest patch level installed we have lots and lots of weird issues. This only gets worse when you have 2 repositories in order to test a new release of PowerDesigner. PowerDesigner's habit of hardcoding ID's into models make this very problematic.

I know someone who is often hired by SAP as PowerDesigner Instructor. His recommendation is to stay away from the repository and use Git. It has always been a badly integrated add-on with questionable support. The datamodel for the repository is horrible (which is quite ironic) and it seems that foreign keys and relational integrity are foreign concepts to it.

So we are now in the process of moving off the repository and onto TFS. All PowerDesigner models are XML, so TFS or Subversion or Git etc. will do nicely (but we like the locking of TFS/Subversion for this). Yes, we will have to forget about the nice display of changes, but frankly, having a robust version management instead of the buggy and model-destroying repository is worth it.